# Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'decimal' and 'double'

Tags: c#, .net, comparison

I'm trying to come up with a program that calculates grades given from the users input. I am also trying to set a limit on how high or low the user input can be (i.e 0 <= or >= 100). But when I use decimal it keeps giving me this error, "Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'decimal' and 'double'"

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Grade_Program
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string First;
            string Last;
            First = "Cristiano";
            Last = " Ronaldo";
            Console.Write("Please enter student name <First Last>: ");
            Console.WriteLine(First + Last );

            Console.WriteLine(" ");

                                                     Console.WriteLine("*************NOTE**********************************************");
        Console.WriteLine("*** Be sure to include decimal point for scores.            ***");
        Console.WriteLine("***     !!!All score should range from 0.00 to 100.00 !!    ***");
        Console.WriteLine("***                                                         ***");
        Console.WriteLine("*** For example : 80.50                                     ***");
        Console.WriteLine("***************************************************************");

        Console.WriteLine(" ");

        decimal Exam_1;
        decimal Exam_2;
        decimal Exam_3;
        decimal Assignment_1;
        decimal Assignment_2;

        Console.Write("Please enter score for Exam 1 <Example: 100.0>: ");
        Exam_1 = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());

        if (Exam_1 < 0.0 | Exam_1 > 100.0)
            Console.Write("Exam score cannot be less than 0. or greater than                      100.0. Please re-enter the score for Exam 1 <Example: 95.0>:");
            Exam_1 = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("Please enter score for Exam 2 <Example: 0.0>: ");
        Exam_2 = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());
```

Comment: Try `0M <= myDecimal || 100M >= myDecimal` (ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx)

Comment: Most of the time this error comes because of casting problem. If you paste  the code we can give a right answer exactly.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There are at least *four* issues I noticed in your code.

**Firstly**, as mentioned, you should use `M` suffix to tell the C# compiler that it is a `decimal` for accepted comparison:

```
if (Exam_1 < 0.0M | Exam_1 > 100.0M)
```

But **secondly**, use `||` instead of `|`, because you want to do `OR` operation, not `Bitwise-OR`

```
if (Exam_1 < 0.0M || Exam_1 > 100.0M) //change | to ||
```

And **thirdly**, I think quite important for you to know this: you ***wouldn't need*** `decimal` data type for exam mark (unless your exam mark can be of format 99.12345678901234556789012345 - which is quite impossible).

`decimal` is normally used for numbers requiring very high precision (such as `money` calculation in the bank) up to more than 16-digit accuracy. If your exam mark does not need that, *don't* use `decimal`, it is *overkill*. Just use `double` or `int` or `float` for your `Exams` and you are most probably in the right track.

**Fourthly**, about your error handling, this is incorrect way of doing it:

```
if (Exam_1 < 0.0 | Exam_1 > 100.0)
    Console.Write("Exam score cannot be less than 0. or greater than                      100.0. Please re-enter the score for Exam 1 <Example: 95.0>:");
    Exam_1 = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());
```

due to two reasons:

1. Your `Exam_1` is outside of the block (there isn't `{}` bracket)
2. You use `if` while you should use `while`

This is the right way to do it:

```
double Exam_1 = -1; //I use double to simplify

Console.Write("Please enter score for Exam 1 <Example: 100.0>: ");
Exam_1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

while (Exam_1 < 0.0 || Exam_1 > 100.0) { //see the curly bracket
    Console.Write("Exam score cannot be less than 0. or greater than                      100.0. Please re-enter the score for Exam 1 <Example: 95.0>:");
    Exam_1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
} //see the end curly bracket
```

In C# language, indentation does not mean scoping, unlike in language like Python.

Comment: @Abdulhamid no... your error handling ("loop" in your term, but actually it is not) seems to be another problem... unfortunately..

Comment: May you shed light on the-the issue so I don't run into it in the future?

Comment: While scanning through, I noticed that the way you just gave me, does not limit the user input to "Decimal" (i.e 2.0 instead of 2)

Comment: @Abdulhamid yes, normally we don't force the user to put the additional zeros when it does not change the value. This is because the `Convert.ToDouble` behavior can distinguish that. If you want to put the restriction like putting `.00`, then even `decimal` would not have any effect. What you need instead is a custom string checker - which would probably be quite troublesome to make with little benefits. Therefore, people usually don't do that.

Answer (score 5):

For decimal you have to add "M" suffix to the value to tell the computer it is a decimal. Otherwise computer will consider it as a double.

yourDecimal < 98.56M;

Answer (score 1):

As other's have already pointed out. In order to compare a `decimal` type using the greater than or less than operators you must compare it to another `decimal` type. In order to declare a literal number as a decimal it requires the `M` or `m` suffix. Here is the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx) on the `decimal` type for reference.

```
if (Exam_1 < 0.0m || Exam_1 > 100.0m)
```

[Here's a .NET fiddle with the fix.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GD7hfk)