# How to apply == decimal value in if condition?

Tags: c#, operators, c#-6.0

This is the logic I have been trying to execute but it is giving issues:

```
protected void Price_Update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    decimal Price;   
    var gvr   = (GridViewRow)(sender as Control).Parent.Parent;
    int index = gvr.RowIndex;
    var box1  = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[index].Cells[4].FindControl("TextBox1");
    bool prc  = decimal.TryParse(box1.Text, out Price);
    var PriceString = GridView1.Rows[index].Cells[4].Text.Replace(" AUD", "");

    var btn = (Button)sender;
    var row = (GridViewRow)btn.NamingContainer;
    var ProductNo = row.Cells[0].Text;
    var BranchNo  = row.Cells[6].Text;

    if (Price > 00.00)
    {
        var CS  = "data source=LAPTOP-ODS96MIK\\MSSQL2014; database = Grocery_Demo; integrated security=SSPI";
        var con = new SqlConnection(CS);
        var cmd = new SqlCommand("UpdateProductQuantity", con);

        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        con.Open();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductPrice", Price);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductNo", ProductNo);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GroceryBranchNo", BranchNo);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

        MessageBox("Price has been updated");
        DisplayProducts();
    }
    else if (Price == 00.00 || prc == false)
    {
        Label5.Text = "Please don't keep the price blank";
        DisplayProducts();
    }
}
```

The issue I'm facing is that there is red line under both the if conditions and it is saying that:

> Operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'decimal' and 'double'

I still couldn't figure out where is the trick that I'm missing out.

It would be helpful if the appropriate syntax solution is provided.

Comment: Try Price > 0m   m indicates decimal literal Also Price == 0m

Comment: Add an "m", like 0.00m to make it a Decimal

Comment: unbelievable, I really cannot find a duplicate for the `==` operator. Although the logic of operators in this case, can be transfered to any comparison operator.

Comment: still I think that [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35858177/operator-cannot-be-applied-to-operands-of-type-decimal-and-double) should answer your question. If I relate to the error message that you have posted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, the error caused by you can't use `==` to compare between `double` and `decimal`.

```
Console.WriteLine((00.00).GetType()); // type is double
```

we can see the type of `00.00` is `double`,  but Your `Price` value is `decimal` type, so they can't be compared.

You need to add or `M` at the end of the number because `00.00` mean the value is `double`. `m` can let it become decimal.

[decimal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/decimal)

> If you want a numeric real literal to be treated as decimal, use the suffix m or M

```
if (Price > 00.00m)
```