# NumericUpDown greater than label value

Tags: c#, operator-keyword

How do use an if statement for numericUpDown value is less than label value?

**Error**:

> operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'decimal'.

```
       if (lblCookieInventory.Text < numCookiesSold.Value)
        {

            // subtract item sold
            cs.CookieInventory = cs.CookieInventory - System.Convert.ToInt32(numCookiesSold.Value);

            // calculate invenotry value
            cs.CookieInventoryPrice = cs.CookieInventory * cs.CookiePrice;

            // return to list
            CookieScout[index] = cs;

            //re-display
            DisplayCookie();

            // clear number sold
            numCookiesSold.Value = 0;
        }
        // Update datafile
        UpdateCookieTextFile();
    }
```

Comment: dupicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35858177/operator-cannot-be-applied-to-operands-of-type-decimal-and-double

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're comparing a string to a decimal type. Change `lblCookieInventory.Text`to `Decimal.Parse(lblCookieInventory.Text)` and it will work.